# problem with Vaadin 23 - combobox component

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, renderer, vaadin23

I have a problem with new Vaadin 23 and Combobox component:

```
combo.setRenderer(LitRenderer.<Model>of(
                "<div>${item.getNumber}<br><small><i>Qty Certified in Stock: </i>:${item.certified}</small></div>")
                .withProperty("heatnumber", Model::getNumber)
                .withProperty("certified", Model::getQtyStockCertified));
comboHeatNumber.setOpened(true);
```

Don't work. I have to remove the renderer to make it open without clicking.

Comment: getNumber  != heatnumber, thus renderer fails and your ComboBox popup is empty and nothing is shown.

Comment: @TatuLund , what you said is incorrect. The combo works perfectly, the only problem is that it doesn't stay open.
As suggested, I solved it like this:
** combo.getElement().executeJs("setTimeout(() => this.opened = true, 0);"); **